# What does Facebook Use to load the new Hashtags when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, user-interface

I am working on a website, and I really like the new popup page that comes up when you click a hastag.I have been trying to implement something like this for a long period of time, but I have no idea how to do it.. Is this done using JavaScript?

Comment: ...well, yess, that's the main way ;-)  . I'll let this Q go, but this is too general/unformed for SO . but i'll let you on ur way ;-)  . Facebook has its own "flavor" if u will. google FaceBook - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I'm the creator of the following library.

If you are looking for a structured way of implementing these you can check out popscript.js, the [source](https://github.com/relfor/popscript) is available on github.

Once you have included the files as explained in [this part](https://github.com/relfor/popscript#loading-popscript) of the docs, to push out a pop up containing an html node (which can have child nodes as well) you would issue the following:

```
pop(<node_goes_here>)
```

Trying to take a approximate guess at what your code will roughly look like:

```
button.onclick = function () {
    var list_wrapper = document.createElement('ul');
    // Some loop goes here to add list items to the above
    // created list
    pop(list_wrapper);
}
```

The boilerplate code given is sufficient to get started with really swiftly,
if you need any further help with achieving the pop ups you are currently visioning then
do let me know.